# Duplicate html when adding to textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this little js which adds divs and its content on a click as plain text in the textarea:

```
  var content = " ";
  jQuery('body').on('click', '.btn_video', function() {
    if(jQuery(this).text()=="ADD") {
      jQuery(this).text("REMOVE");
      jQuery(this).parents(".thumbnail").parent().addClass('selected');
    } else{
      jQuery(this).text("ADD");
      jQuery(this).parents(".thumbnail").parent().removeClass('selected');
    }
    jQuery('.selected').each(function(){
      content += jQuery(this).prop('outerHTML');
    });
    jQuery('#usp-custom-5').val(content);
  });
```

This is the html that is added on a click

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+e.id+'?rel=0&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <p>Duration: <span class="video-time">'+YTDurationToSeconds(e.contentDetails.duration)+'</span></p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn_video"><strong>ADD</strong></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+e.id+'?rel=0&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <p>Duration: <span class="video-time">'+YTDurationToSeconds(e.contentDetails.duration)+'</span></p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn_video"><strong>ADD</strong></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

   <textarea id="usp-custom-5"></textarea>
```

I want to be able to add each html content when I click on the button without having repeated content and also be able to remove the single content when a user clicks on the button.

In the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q5070aa4/4/) if I click on the Add button i get repeated content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `var content = '';` at the beginning of your click function.

https://jsfiddle.net/q5070aa4/5/

what was happening before is that you were taking whatever content existed and adding whatever element text that was `"selected"` - and this would produce your duplicate data. you want to clear out the textarea on click so that only the `"selected"` elements text shows

Answer (score 1):

try this: you can add remove selected class to div and read all div with selected class to get content and replace it in text area

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".btn.btn-danger.btn-block").on("click", function(){
        var text = $(this).text();
      if(text=="ADD") {
        jQuery(this).find("strong").text("REMOVE");
        jQuery(this).closest(".col-xs-12.col-md-4").addClass("selected");
      } else if(text == "REMOVE") {
       jQuery(this).find("strong").text("ADD");
       jQuery(this).closest(".col-xs-12.col-md-4").removeClass("selected");
      }
      var content = "";
      jQuery(".col-xs-12.col-md-4.selected").each(function(){
            content += '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">' + $(this).html() + '</div>';
      });
      jQuery('#usp-custom-5').val(content);
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q5070aa4/6/)**

Comment: hey thanks, why is this better than the answer given previously?

Comment: actually i got late in posting this answer , but make it more cleaner